# Modal launch button with actionlistener

Tags: jsf, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to use a f:setPropertyActionListener on a Bootstrap modal launch button but it doesn't work at all. Tags *a* and *button* don't support it so I don't know what to do now.
I need to set an id of an item in a bean I have when I push the modal launch button, so I can then confirm delete that item using the modal.

I've searched here and on other sites and I've found a lot of solutions to my specific problem using Javascript but I have no idea about that :/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't use a `h:button`, which gets rendered as a button at client side?

Comment: I've tried it but it can't be used with f:setPropertyActionListener. Do you know something similar that I can use with the h:button tag?

Comment: Which JSF version-impl are you dealing with? Probably you'll need a `h:commandButton` instead. http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-setpropertyactionlistener-example/

Comment: I've tried that too but it can't use the href option I need to call my modal, that's why I tried to use tags _a_ and _button_ because both can use href.

Comment: Why do you need an `href`? Isn't the button suposed to act as a plain javascript launcher? `href` is used to link an external resource. What you want to do is to show a model panel (as far as I understood in the question), so think about it.